# Dropbox installation fails

Tags: python, software-center, dropbox

Dropbox fails to install on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 18.04.3. I first tried to install via the Software Center. When that failed, I followed directions [here](https://help.dropbox.com/installs-integrations/desktop/uninstall-dropbox) to remove files, then tried the headless installation via command line. The command `~/.dropbox-dist/dropboxd` returns the following:

```
dropbox: locating interpreter
dropbox: logging to /tmp/dropbox-antifreeze-26w5b7
dropbox: initializing
dropbox: initializing python 3.7.2
dropbox: setting program path '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/dropbox'
dropbox: setting home path '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155'
dropbox: setting python path '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155:/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/python-packages-37.zip'
dropbox: python initialized
dropbox: running dropbox
dropbox: setting args
dropbox: applying overrides
dropbox: running main script
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cryptography.hazmat.bindings._padding.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/psutil._psutil_linux.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/psutil._psutil_posix.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.pthread._linuxffi_pthread.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/cpuid.compiled._cpuid.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/apex._apex.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/tornado.speedups.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.resolv.compiled._linuxffi_resolv.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/librsyncffi.compiled._librsyncffi.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.sys.compiled._linuxffi_sys.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/posixffi.libc._posixffi_libc.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
dropbox: load fq extension '/home/ian/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-85.4.155/linuxffi.gnu.compiled._linuxffi_gnu.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7919, in main
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7843, in main_startup
  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 942, in __init__
  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 147, in make_default_file_system
  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 99, in __init__
  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 118, in _initialize_classes
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/sync_engine.pyc", line 276, in <module>
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/thin_adapter/in_proc.pyc", line 98, in <module>
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/wrapped_thin_client.pyc", line 26, in <module>
  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/thin_client/client.pyc", line 28, in <module>
  File "dropbox/foundation/metrics/amp/remote_sink.pyc", line 10, in <module>
ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
!! dropbox: fatal python exception:
['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7919, in main\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 7843, in main_startup\n', '  File "dropbox/client/main.pyc", line 942, in __init__\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 147, in make_default_file_system\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 99, in __init__\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine_boundary/factory.pyc", line 118, in _initialize_classes\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/sync_engine.pyc", line 276, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/thin_adapter/in_proc.pyc", line 98, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/classic_client/wrapped_thin_client.pyc", line 26, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/sync_engine/nucleus/thin_client/client.pyc", line 28, in <module>\n', '  File "dropbox/foundation/metrics/amp/remote_sink.pyc", line 10, in <module>\n', 'ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n'] (error 3)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the required [files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libatomic1/filelist), the files provided by packages which you can install as follow.

```
sudo apt-get install libatomic1
```

Try running the Dropbox daemon again.